# Generic method to accept specific object or its subtype

Tags: java, generics

How to make generic method that will accept a specific `MyObject` or subtype of `MyObject`. Something like the below:

```
public static Response sendResponse(accept MyObject or subtype of MyObject) {
    return response
}
```

Comment: MyObject can hold itself and its subclasses also... is that you want ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand. Your code don't look like a generic method.

And you can just do that :

```
public static Response sendResponse(MyObject parameter){
    return response
}
```

Maybe you need to read this links :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want a generic method, you can write:

```
public static <T extends MyObject> Response sendResponse(T object){
    return response;
}
```

There is no practical difference between this and the obvious non-generic solution.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment? This is so far the only answer to the question as it has been written.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need generics for that. It's basic Java.

Imagine:

```
public class Vehicle {...}

public class Car extends Vehicle {...}

public class Utils {
  public void doSomething(Vehicle v) {...}
}
```

This is OK:

```
Cay myCar = new Car();
Utils.doSomething(myCar); //can call with any subclass of Vehicle
```